# Ethereum Boardcast shows error: non-canonical integer (leading zero bytes) for *big.Int, decoding into (types.Transaction)(types.txdata).S"

Tags: ether, raw-transaction

I meet with a problem, does someone can help me how to deal with leading zero in raw-transaction?
My raw transaction is: f86b0285012a05f2008261a8948b733353ce21ebd8eb5ffd9f49d57830942e88158769ec95a3fa70008025a04f9dd75069b51d36ec47b5bf68e6c45f8b854cf17a661e734e7a7c651240eeaca00044280475c3d355c44829ac93118b4ebe044356185c1c08724c8bcfebbd4b3d

Boardcast shows error: non-canonical integer (leading zero bytes) for *big.Int, decoding into (types.Transaction)(types.txdata).S"

including raw-transaction:
R is 4f9dd75069b51d36ec47b5bf68e6c45f8b854cf17a661e734e7a7c651240eeac
S is 0044280475c3d355c44829ac93118b4ebe044356185c1c08724c8bcfebbd4b3d

How can I deal with leading zero, and how can I re-construction raw-transaction after correct it?
Does the process like this?
RLP{ RLP(nonce) + RLP(Gas price) + RLP(Gas limit) + RLP(to address) + RLP(value) + RLP(data) + V + [a0 + FixLeadingZero(R)] + [a0 + FixLeadingZero(S)] }

Answer (score 3):

This error happened because, in this case, S has leading zero bytes

```
R: 4f 9d d7 50 69 b5 1d 36 ....
S: 00 44 28 04 75 c3 d3 55 ....
   ↑ not allowed while RLP decoding
```

While decoding, geth treated R & S as integer, meaning leading zero is not legal to process.

In order to solve this issue, you simply have to remove leading zeros and RLP it.

---

you understand raw transaction as :

> RLP{ RLP(nonce) + RLP(Gas price) + RLP(Gas limit) + RLP(to address) +
>   RLP(value) + RLP(data) + V + [a0 + FixLeadingZero(R)] + [a0 +
>   FixLeadingZero(S)] }

but that isn't right, `0xa0` is not a fixed byte, it's the first byte of RLP code, which represent the length of trailing data. 
( For more detail of RLP implementation you can check out here : 
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%5BEnglish%5D-RLP )

Since R & S is usually 32 bytes, so first byte usually is `0x80 + 32 = 0xa0`, but as i mentioned above, it won't always be that way.

In this case, since we trim 1 byte, so the first byte of RLP code is `0x80 + 31 = 0x9f`

So after triming, S in raw transaction shouldn't be : `a044280475c3d355c44829ac93118b4ebe044356185c1c08724c8bcfebbd4b3d`

it should be : `9f44280475c3d355c44829ac93118b4ebe044356185c1c08724c8bcfebbd4b3d`

and the format of raw transaction should be :

```
raw transaction = RLP( RLP(nonce) + RLP(gas price) + RLP(gas limit) +
                       RLP(to) + RLP(value) + RLP(data) +
                       V + RLP(trimLeadingZero(R)) + RLP(trimLeadingZero(S)) )
```

where `+` means concatenate.